# How to connect to other databases (1 to 15) than default database (0) in stackexchange redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, default-database

I have 3 applications pointing to single redis endpoint. I want to use separate redis database per application. But when I am trying to set defaultDatabase to 1 or 2 in ConfigurationOption it is still using database 0. I am using stackexchange redis. Code is as given below :

```
  var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { "myredis.redis.cache.windows.net" },
            Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            Ssl = true,
            ConfigurationChannel = "MyRedis",
            ChannelPrefix = "MR",
            DefaultDatabase = 1,
        };

        var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);

        var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(connectionMultiplexer, new JilSerializer(), database: 1);
```

Now adding new key to cache using ICacheClient

```
 var user = new User()
 {
     Id = 100,
     Name = "John Doe"
 };

var response = cacheClient.Add("mykey", user);
```

Then retrieving added key from cache

```
var addedUser= cacheClient.Get<string>("mykey");
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Ideally as per stated in configuration options it should store keys to db1 but it is storing to db0 instead.

Comment: It looks like perhaps you're using [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core)? `StackExchangeRedisCacheClient` isn't part of the core SE.Redis library.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the database object, you should specify the database number. https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html#using-a-redis-database

Comment: I am using ICacheClient to perform all redis operations and not dealing with database directly.

Comment: I see. You'll have to check the docs for the `ICacheClient` to see if it supports multiple databases.